# Changing iframe source within multiple tags. javascript function isn't working

Tags: javascript, function, iframe

I'm trying to execute a javascript function that would change the source code for each iframe. It works if the iframe is not within any other tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
<iframe src="https://www.espn.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.nbc.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.cnn.com"  frameborder="1" width="500" height="320"></iframe>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
  alert("Hello!");
  var frames = window.frames;
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
    frames[i].location = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    }  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How ever if I put the iframe within div tags the javascript for some reason doesn't reach them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <form align = "center">
      <br>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
      <br>
    </form>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-6">
    <h3 id = "ESPN">ESPN</h3>
       <iframe src="https://www.espn.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-6">
    <h3 id = "NBC">NBC</h3>
      <iframe src="https://www.nbc.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-6">
    <h3 id = "CNN">CNN</h3>
      <iframe src="https://www.cnn.com"  frameborder="1" width="500" height="320"></iframe>
      <br>
</div>
</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
  alert("Hello!");
  var frames = window.frames;
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
    frames[i].location = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    }  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something else I need to do in order for my function to read the iframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  function myFunction(){
  alert("Hello!");
  var frames = window.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); // You only want iframes
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
    frames[i].src = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var frames = window.querySelectorAll("iframe");
```

to get all iframes.
Im not sure but you may also change your line to
`frames[i].src = "http://www.w3schools.com";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
frames[i].src= "http://www.w3schools.com";
```

insted of that

```
frames[i].location = "http://www.w3schools.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your javascript with the following:

```
function myFunction() {
            alert("Hello!");
            var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
            for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
                frames[i].src = "http://www.w3schools.com";
            }
        }
```

Comment: For clarity, could you explain what the mistake in the original code was that your solution addresses?

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong in your code. Bt since document.getElementByTagName is restricted to look in only the document object of which it is a method, It is more elegant method. By the way, your code worked without any problem here...